# Resize Raster according to screen size in PaperJS

Tags: paperjs

I would like resize a Raster (image) when I resize the canvas via PaperJS. I'm using the following codes:

```
var last_point = view.center;
var img = new Raster('images/test.png', view.center);
img.onLoad = function() {
    resizeImg();
}
function onResize(event) {
    view.scrollBy(last_point.subtract(view.center));
    last_point = view.center;
    resizeImg();
}
function resizeImg() {
    var width = paper.view.size.width; 
    var scale = (width / img.width) * 0.75;
    img.scale(scale);
}
```

However, once going through `resizeImg()` function, the image is gone (commented the function out will make the image re-appear).

What did I miss in the function? *I guess it's just a simple mistake in calculation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object's width is referenced by its `bounds.width` property, not `width` alone.

```
function resizeImg() {
    var width = paper.view.size.width; 
    var scale = (width / img.bounds.width) * 0.75;
    img.scale(scale);
}
```

Comment: Excellent. It works like charm! Seems official documentation missed a lot useful examples...

Answer (score 0):

The following preserves the aspect ratio of the image and spares you the trouble of doing math stuff. `fitBounds` ([doc](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#fitbounds-rectangle)) and `view.onFrame` ([doc](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#onframe)) make it all work automatically.

```
…

function resizeImg () {
  img.fitBounds(view.bounds)
}

view.onFrame = function (event) {
  resizeImg()
}
```